# Why do i get ImageIO errors in console?

Tags: xcode, console, uiimageview, gif, javax.imageio

Why do i get error ImageIO:  _CGImagePluginInitGIFmalformed GIF file (768 x 1024)?

I am going crazy! This error shows up in XCode console when some of my .gif images need to show up in UIImageView. Images do not display(!) and I get that in console. That error is showing only for few images, not all! I tried to remove the images, add them again, clean, rebuild, but I still cant display those images! Everything was OK until I installed XCode 4.0.1, all images were working and displaying fine! Some people said that this is a bug in XCode and that it is necessary to install latest version 4.0.2. I did that and the problem is still here! I googled and searched here but it seems that this kind of error is not common... I really don't know what's going on. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: When I compile for iOS 3.2 everything seems fine, no errors, and images are displaying ok. Problem is only when I compile for iOS 4.2, 4.3.. No one had this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question... Long story short; I contacted Apple Technical support for developers. It is a bug related with .gif images. For now, workaround is to use .png or some other image type.