# <Error>: ImageIO: processAPP1 Failed to read tag #4 in mainIFD error in xcode log console

Tags: xcode, ios6, tags

I have an app that repeat showing the following errors on the logs:

`<Error>: ImageIO: readTag : tag-id '0000' is bad (type = 1  count = 1) - ignoring...`

and

`<Error>: ImageIO: processAPP1 Failed to read tag #4 in mainIFD.`

anyone can point how to solve it and why it happens ?

Comment: I'm getting the same exact error and can't figure out the source. Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: someone said somewhere that its related to Apple internal APIs and it can/should be ignored, but never got a solid answer

Answer (score 0):

This was the best answer I could find https://stackoverflow.com/a/5782332/819694. Replacing GIF images with PNGs helped.

Comment: its been a while since the question was asked, the reason it happend was that during the pre release/beta versions of the sdks